# Targeting different .NET platform with csc.exe 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-2.0

I had installed .NET 4 on my system and found that the produced exe is using CLR 4.0. Is there an option with the `csc.exe` to target CLR 2.0?

I am using Notepad++ currently. (SharpDevelop works but I need to know how it works)

Like I can select c# version and .NET version in sharp develop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/noconfig /nostdlib` and then explicitly reference the .NET 2.0 assemblies (in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` for example). It looks like the `/lib` command line option can make this slightly easier by letting you specify a directory to look in for references

Comment: Then would the compiler produce .NET 2.0 assemblies?